# Convert range limited float to unsigned int maintaining sort order and precision?

Tags: c++, c, types, casting

I have a float `z_f` that is clamped between 0.0f and 1.0f and I want to convert this to an unsigned integer that maintains sort order.

A simple way to do this might be:

```
float z_f = 0.5;
unsigned int z_ui = (unsigned int) z_f*(MAX_UINT32);//Scale to full range of uint32
```

Will this work?
Will this cause a loss in precision?
Is there a better way to achieve same result?

Comment: Why the C-style cast and why don't you use `std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max()` (or do you?)

Comment: One question that arises is why you need the whole operation, why do you want to convert to `unsigned int` in the first place? The restrictions on ordering may hint that you just want to perform a fast sort operation as integers, if that is the case, there are better alternatives that don't involve loosing precision

Comment: I have the similar problems - here are some hints:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24360347/converting-float-to-uint32-which-expression-is-more-precise

Answer (score 2):

The type conversion `(unsigned int) z_f` has higher precedence than the binary `*`, so you are effectively multiplying `MAX_UINT32` with 0 or 1.

Answer (score 2):

There are many possible values of `z_f` that would map to the same integer (think of the many floats that are very close to zero). This could potentially affect the sort order.

There's also the precedence bug pointed out by @Oswald.

As to a better way, I am not sure (other than keeping the numbers as floats).

Answer (score 0):

I would first avoid the C style casts, for precedence reasons. The second thing is that you don't want to do this operation on a `float` due to precission issues, but rather in a `double`.

```
unsigned int z_ui 
                 = static_cast<unsigned int>(satic_cast<double>(z_f)*MAX_UINT32);
```

Comment: I'm constrained to floats by hardware.

Comment: @CodeFusionMobile: I am not 100% sure, but if you are constrained to `float` there is not enough significant bits in `float` to map to all of the unsigned int, so you will be loosing precision and some of the values that differ in the original `float` might be the same in the `unsigned int` representation. Not sure if this is the case, but that is my feeling.