# Converting float to UInt32 - which expression is more precise

Tags: c#, floating-point, floating-point-precision, numerical-stability

I have a number `float x` which should be in <0,1> range but it undergo several numerical operations - the result may be slightly outside <0,1>.

I need to convert this result to `uint y` using entire range of `UInt32`. Of course, I need to clamp `x` in the <0,1> range and scale it.

But which order of operations is better?

```
y = (uint)round(min(max(x, 0.0F), 1.0F) * UInt32.MaxValue)
```

or

```
y = (uint)round(min(max(x * UInt32.MaxValue, 0.0F), UInt32.MaxValue)
```

In another words, it is better to scale first, then clamp OR clamp and then scale? I am not very profound in the IEEE floating point representation, but I believe there is a difference in the order of computation of the above expressions.

Comment: @Duncan I think the problem is not language-specific since both Java and C# use IEEE floating point representations for floats.

Comment: It may be helpful for the down-voters to leave comments. This question seems quite valid to me. Perhaps it was the mis-tagging that encouraged some down-voting...

Comment: Okay, I've left the C# tag... the question should be more valid.

Comment: Java does not have `UInts`.. (or any other unsigned datatypes for that matter)

Comment: Sure, I have missed this - anyway, the problem applies to `Int32` as well.

Comment: Overflows are handled differently.. Int32 overflow turns into a negative number, which is outside your interval, UInt32 overflows turn into a number in your interval.

Comment: @flindeberg Sure - I wasn't actually expecting any overflow happening, but this it the problem with second approach. It was noted it causes overflow for `x = 1.0f`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the multiplication to get from [0.0f .. 1.0f] to [0 .. UInt32.MaxValue] can itself be approximative, the order of operations that most obviously has the property you desire is multiply, then clamp, then round.

The maximum value to clamp to is the float immediately below 2<sup>32</sup>, that is, `4294967040.0f`. Although this number is several units below UInt32.MaxValue, allowing any larger value would mean overflowing the conversion to `UInt32`.

Either of the lines below should work:

```
y = (uint)round(min(max(x * 4294967040.0F, 0.0F), 4294967040.0F))
```

In this first version, you have the option to multiply by `UInt32.MaxValue` instead. The choice is between having very slightly larger results overall (and thus rounding to 4294967040 a few more values that were close to 1.0f but below it), or only sending to 4294967040 the values 1.0f and above.

---

You can also clamp to [0.0f .. 1.0f] **if you do not multiply by too large a number afterwards**, so that there is no risk of making the value larger than the largest float that can be converted:

```
y = (uint)round(min(max(x, 0.0F), 1.0F) * 4294967040.0F)
```

---

Suggestion for your comment below, about crafting a conversion that goes up to `UInt32.MaxValue`:

```
if (x <= 0.0f) y = 0
else if (x < 0.5f) y = (uint) round (x * 4294967296.0F)
else if (x >= 1.0f) y = UInt32.MaxValue
else y = UInt32.MaxValue - (uint) round ((1.0f - x) * 4294967296.0F)
```

This computation considered as a function from `x` to `y` is increasing (including around 0.5f) and it goes up to `UInt32.MaxValue`. You can re-order the tests according to what you think will be the most likely distribution of values. In particular, assuming that few values are actually below 0.0f or above 1.0f, you can compare to 0.5f first, and then only compare to the bound that is relevant:

```
if (x < 0.5f)
{
  if (x <= 0.0f) y = ...
  else y = ...
}
else
{
  if (x >= 1.0f) y = ...
  else y = ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This answers the question. My original problem is however bit more complicated since 1.0f should map to UInt32.MaxValue (and vice versa) and the intermediate values as uniformly as possible. It is for a color management system where both 1.0f and UInt32.MaxValue represents white and it needs to convert between the two representation without introducing non-uniform jumps in values. It is also implemented on graphics hardware that supports only floats. But this is another question...

Comment: @Libor I saw your comment about being unable to use `Double`. You can convert to `UInt32` with the property you desire (reaching `UInt32.MaxValue`) by using converting two floats instead, but do you really prefer 3-4 additional float operations and perhaps a conditional branch to the straightforward `Double` implementation?

Comment: Sure it would be more straightforward. The problem is my C# code is translated to OpenCL and unlike today's CPUs, not all GPUs support double-precision. Even mentioning double variable in code would cause a compile-time exception. I think I will compose a more appropriate question addressing this.

Comment: @Libor please look at my edit. The syntax may not be correct C# (I read this question because of the floating-point tag), but I think this may be the most straightforward solution.

Comment: Thanks for the ready-made solution and even cleaning this up! I hope more people will benefit from this. Yes the most straightforward solution is not always the nicest one (if you have ever seen Johm Carmack's original code for Quake, there is some floating-point black magic, he even did this on a binary level).

Comment: `if (x < 0.5f)`, you want to multiply by 2^32, not 2^31.

Comment: @tmyklebu I think I want to multiply by 2^32 in all cases. I mixed up this solution with another beginning of a solution I was thinking of at the time.

Comment: Color format conversions that use round are almost always incorrect, because the bins that map to the minimum and maximum results are usually too small by half. This isn’t as critical with high precision formats like uint32, but it’s still important.

Answer (score 2):

The three essential attributes of correct color format conversion are:

- black must map to black and white must map to white (meaning 0.0 —> 0 and 1.0 —> 2^32-1 in this case)
- the intervals in the source format which map to each value in the destination format must have widths that are as equal as possible.
- evenly spaced inputs should map to outputs that are as evenly spaced as possible in the destination format.

A corollary of the second point is that color format conversions that use round are almost always incorrect, because the bins that map to the minimum and maximum results are usually too small by half. This isn’t as critical with high precision formats like uint32, but it’s still good to get right.

You mentioned in a comment that your C# code is being translated to OpenCL.  OpenCL has by far the nicest set of conversions of any language I’ve encountered (seriously, if you’re designing a compute-oriented language and you don’t copy what OpenCL did here, you’re doing it wrong), which makes this pretty easy:

```
convert_uint_sat(x * 0x1.0p32f)
```

However, your question is actually about C#; I’m not a C# programmer, but the approach there should look something like this:

```
if (x <= 0.0F) y = UInt32.MinValue;
else if (x >= 1.0F) y = UInt32.MaxValue;
else y = (uint)Math.Truncate(x * 4294967296.0F);
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen for a nice answer. I have finally used float instad of uint. I found that float has enough values between `0.0f` and `1.0f` for all thinkable high dynamic range color applications (and the ability to go off-gamut is also a welcome feature). Its processing is also fast enough. UInt32 often required intermediate Int64s which may need more instructions on GPU than float. I hope I will make use of your conversion formula anyway.

Comment: @Libor: that’s probably wise.  I’m yet to encounter a graphics/imaging situation where `float` doesn't suffice for the color space.

Answer (score 0):

Given that `x` might be slightly outside `[0,1]` the second approach is not as easy as the first one due to clamping issues in UInt32-valuespace, ie every number in UInt32 is valid. The first one is also easier to understand, ie get a number in an interval and scale.

Ie:

```
var y = (UInt32) (Math.Min(Math.Max(x, 0f), 1f) * UInt32.MaxValue);
```

Also, I tested it with a couple of millions of values, they give the same result. It doesn't matter which one you use.

Comment: What do you mean by "not as easy"? This is a question about floating-point precision, not ease of reading.

Comment: That it is more of a hassle to do the clamping since the entire value space is valid for UInt32, instead of the [0,1] limit in float / single.

Comment: If you clamp first, **then multiply,** then round, you run the risk of the multiplication taking your value back out of range. Indeed, `UInt32.MaxValue` is not representable as a float and is rounded up when converted to float, so that `1.0F * UInt32.MaxValue` is a float representing a value larger than `UInt32.MaxValue`. The most obviously correct approach seems to multiply, then clamp, then convert to `UInt32`.

Comment: @PascalCuoq You are right. `1.0f * UInt32.MaxValue` is equal to `UInt32.MaxValue + 1` and the expression `(uint)(1.0f * UInt32.MaxValue)` overflows to `0`. Could you make this an answer so that I can accept it? I will edit the answer adding details if needed, just want to give you the credit.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Funnily enough, `Math.Min(UInt32.MaxValue + 1.0f, UInt32.MaxValue)` still resolves to `UInt32.MaxValue + 1.0f`. I cannot use `double`s (for hardware reasons) so the final conversion to `uint` seems to be by treating the special case `x == 1.0f` separately.

Comment: @Libor `UInt32.MaxValue + 1.0f` resolves to `single` (ie `float`) which doesn't have that kind of precision in the `UInt32.MaxValue` range.

Comment: @flindeberg Yes, the precision loss is no problem. The only requirement for the function is to convert float in range [0,1] to UInt32 in range [0, UInt32.MaxValue] so that 1 maps to UInt32.MaxValue and the rest of the interval is mapped as uniformly as possible. I cannot use Double because this code translates to GPU supporting only floats...

Comment: @Libor Indeed, I only took "Funnily enough, Math.Min(UInt32.MaxValue + 1.0f, UInt32.MaxValue) still resolves to UInt32.MaxValue + 1.0f" and answered it :) `var t = (float) UInt32.MaxValue; for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; i++) t += 1f; if (t == (float) UInt32.MaxValue) Console.WriteLine("The same"); else Console.WriteLine("Not the same"); `

Answer (score 0):

Single can't support enough accuracy to maintain the interim result, so you'll need to scale then clamp, but you can't clamp to UInt32.MaxValue because it can't be represented by single. The maximum UInt32 you can safely clamp to is **4294967167**

from this code here

```
        Single maxUInt32 = (Single)UInt32.MaxValue;
        Double accurateValue = maxUInt32;
        while (true)
        {
            accurateValue -= 1;
            Single temp = (Single)accurateValue;
            Double temp2 = (Double)temp;
            if (temp2 < (Double)UInt32.MaxValue)
                break;
        }
```

See this test...

```
        Double val1 = UInt32.MaxValue;
        Double val2 = val1 + 1;

        Double valR = val2 / val1;

        Single sValR = (Single)valR;

        //Straight Scale and Cast
        UInt32 NewValue = (UInt32)(sValR * UInt32.MaxValue);
        //Result = 0;

        //Clamp Then Scale Then Cast
        UInt32 NewValue2 = (UInt32)(Math.Min(sValR, 1.0f) * UInt32.MaxValue);
        //Result = 0;

        //Scale Then Clamp Then Cast
        UInt32 NewValue3 = (UInt32)(Math.Min(sValR * UInt32.MaxValue, UInt32.MaxValue));
        //Result = 0;

        //Using Doubles
        //Straight Scale and Cast
        UInt32 NewValue4 = (UInt32)(valR * UInt32.MaxValue);
        //Result = 0;

        //Clamp Then Scale Then Cast
        UInt32 NewValue5 = (UInt32)(Math.Min(valR, 1.0f) * UInt32.MaxValue);
        //Result = 4294967295;

        //Scale Then Clamp Then Cast
        UInt32 NewValue6 = (UInt32)(Math.Min(valR * UInt32.MaxValue, UInt32.MaxValue));
        //Result = 4294967295;

        //Comparing to 4294967167
        //Straight Scale and Cast
        UInt32 NewValue7 = (UInt32)(sValR * UInt32.MaxValue);
        //Result = 0;

        //Clamp Then Scale Then Cast
        UInt32 NewValue8 = (UInt32)(Math.Min(sValR, 1.0f) * UInt32.MaxValue);
        //Result = 0;

        //Scale Then Clamp Then Cast
        UInt32 NewValue9 = (UInt32)(Math.Min(sValR * UInt32.MaxValue, 4294967167));
        //Result = 4294967040;
```

Comment: Thanks for your test. However, as PascalCuoq noted, the second approach does not hold for `x = 1.0f`. The first approach is safer because of this extreme case.

Comment: @Libor - That was the point, it doesn't matter since the interim result for storing the value ≈UInt32.MaxValue in a float will always overflow the cast. I suppose that means you'll need to multiply then clamp but don't compare to UInt32.MaxValue, instead compare to the largest possible float which is smaller than UInt32.MaxValue

Comment: Oh I see. What I actually need is conversion between `UInt32` and `float` that maps one onto another as uniformly as possible and `UInt32.MaxValue` is mapped to `1.0f`. The backward conversion need not the exactly match the forward mapping, but have to end in interval `0-UInt32.MaxValue`. Maybe this would be a better question to start with.